# Mailer Error Mail() without being connected

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

```
<?php require 'PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php';                    
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug=0;
$mail->isSMTP();                          // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'demotp18@gmail.com';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '****';             // * is just for not to show password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;          
$mail->setFrom('neelsoni.sn@gmail.com');
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
) );

$mail->addAddress('demotp18@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';

 ?>
```

output : Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: The following From address failed: neelsoni.sn@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected

my question is about PHPMAILER 
What is the problem in the code ??
why i get this error ? i turn on less secure in gmail.
And in HOST i tried smtp.gmail.com but there is same error i seen, thats why i found this host type.
same code in my one friend's laptop it's working but another friend is facing this same error.
please help me !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send mail SMTP: Called Mail() without being connected GMAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099484/send-mail-smtp-called-mail-without-being-connected-gmail)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The following From address failed Called Mail() without being connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565056/the-following-from-address-failed-called-mail-without-being-connected)

Comment: As well as failing to search before you posted, you're running a very old, buggy, and vulnerable version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and base your code on [the gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) provided with it.